# How to find all document array key whose size is greater than 2 using $size and $gt in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I want use $gt on size of array in couchdb. I am unable to find any documentation on using $gt with $size.

only $size is working perfectly but when I am using it with $gt it not working.

Example:
 This is working fine

```
"selector": {
      "doc_id": "1080_15465869093608",
      "mapped_id": {
         "$size": 2
      }
   }
```

this is not working.

```
"selector": {
          "doc_id": "1080_15465869093608",
          "mapped_id": {
             "$size": {"$gt": 2}
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just not supported. If you see the documentation of the selectors, you can see that **$size** can only be used with an integer as a value.

https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.1/api/database/find.html#condition-operators